# Unknown Payment Method Nonce

Tags: laravel-4, payment-gateway, braintree

My setup is:

- Laravel 4.2
- Braintreepayments JS + PHP
- [Laravel Braintree](https://github.com/bradleyboy/laravel-braintree)

I tried to add a new customer [as showed in the tutorial](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/sdk/server/customer-management/create#creating-customers) which works fine. But when I tried to add a payment method from the Front-End with the given code from the JavaScript SDK. I used the Drop-In-UI which generates me a **Payment Method Nonce** which is part of my question.

I configured the PHP Backend with the Sandbox credentials and pasted the example Code given in the docs.

When I try to create a user, everything's fine:

```
$result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
    'id' => Auth::id(),
    'firstName' => 'Mike',
    'lastName' => 'Jones',
    'company' => 'Jones Co.',
    'email' => 'mike.jones@example.com',
    'phone' => '281.330.8004',
    'fax' => '419.555.1235',
    'website' => 'http://example.com'
));
```

As soon as it comes to the payment nonce, nothing works:

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'amount' => '10.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => Input::get('payment_method_nonce'),
    'customer' => array(
        'id' => Auth::id()
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
    )
));
```

The server keeps saying `93108: Unknown paymentMethodNonce`. This seems a little bit confusing and strange to me since the `Input::get('payment_method_nonce')` represents a valid string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a very long day with intensive studies of the Documentation i finally found the issue.

You need to pass the [Client Token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/php) which is generated by the PHP Library (not the CSE Token from the Sandbox!) into the JavaScript snippet provided by Braintree:

```
braintree.setup(
        "{{ Braintree_ClientToken::generate(['customerId' => Auth::id()]) }}",
        'dropin', {
            container: 'dropin'
        }
);
```

The Drop-In-UI Code is copy+paste from the doc.

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div id="dropin"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>
```

Hopefully someone saves a lot of time with this answer provided.

**Edit:**
In Laravel 5 you need to manually add the csrf-field (I've updated the code), otherwise you will get a `TokenMismatchException` from Laravel.